# sequence containing at least three consecutive vowels

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function to evaluate if contains at least three vowels consecutively.

I've tried so far:
( I don't know how to evaluate if they are consecutive)
any ideas?

```
def isConsecutive(word):
    # initialize vowel count
vCounter = 0
for letter in word:
    if letter == isVowel(word):  
        vCounter += 1
    else:
        vCounter = 0

    if vCounter < 3:    
        return False
return True
```

## Helper function

```
def isVowel(char):
    return len(char) == 1 and char.lower() in 'aeiou'
```

Comment: Try resetting the counter to 0 if you encounter something else, and stopping if you reach 3.

Comment: There is also regex: `"[aeiouy]{3}"`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I did not learn that yet in class. I was thinking of something like (I've just updated my idea in the post)

Comment: Hi @slartidan , thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check, whether you have reached the third vovel in sequence, should be right after the `vCounter += 1`. If there are three vovels: return true.

Also, the `isVowel` check should be applied to the `letter`, not the whole `word`.

```
def isVowel(char):
    return char.lower() in 'aeiou'

def isConsecutive(word):
    # initialize vowel count
    vCounter = 0
    for letter in word:
        if isVowel(letter): # <= check if the letter is a vowel
            vCounter += 1
            if vCounter >= 3: # <= do the check right here
                return True
        else:
            vCounter = 0

    return False # <= if we did not find three vovels in the loop, then there is none

print "hello: " + str(isConsecutive("hello"))
print "heeello: " + str(isConsecutive("heeello"))
print "hellooo: " + str(isConsecutive("hellooo"))
```

Give it a try online: <kbd>[DEMO](http://tpcg.io/ETCfGG)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also with two list comprehensions:

1. a list of booleans, if the characters in a word are vowels
2. a list of booleans, if there are three consecutive True values in the first list

.

```
def three_consecutive_vowels(s):
    is_vow = [c.lower() in 'aeiou' for c in s]
    three_cons = [all(is_vow[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(is_vow) - 2)]
    return any(three_cons)
```

Test:

```
words = ['hellO', 'heIah', 'aAarrgh']

for w in words:
    print(three_consecutive_vowels(w))

False
True
True
```